# If $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\leq b$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences of real numbers that converges to real numbers $a$ and $b$, respectively. If $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\leq b$.

Could I prove this by contradiction and assume $a>b$?

I am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: Proof by contradiction is a pretty standard approach for solving this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume $a>b$. Now you may proceed as follows:

- Since the distance from $a$ to $b$ is $a-b$, you choose an $\epsilon < \frac{a-b}{2}$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = b$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough such that

- $a_N> a-\epsilon$ and $b_N < b+\epsilon$

Putting this together you get
$$a_N > a -\epsilon > a-\frac{a-b}{2} = \frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$b_N < b +\epsilon < b+\frac{a-b}{2} = \frac{a+b}{2}$$
All together
$$a_N > \frac{a+b}{2} > b_N \mbox{ which contradicts to } a_n \leq b_n \mbox{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: You are welcome :-)